# Unable to use focus on input text in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying the following code but it is not working.

```
 var option=$('<input type="text" value=""/>');
 $(this).append($(option));
 $(option).focus();
```

I also tried to use:

```
$(this).children().first().focus();
```

But that too is not working.

Here is the complete function:

```
var templatestring = "<tr><td class='itemId' style='display:none'></td><td id='tdelement' class='Correct'></td><td id='tdelement' class='Option'></td></td><td id='tdelement' class='Action'><input type='button' value='View' onclick='view(this)'/></td><td id='tdelement' class='Remove'><img src='" + STATIC_URL + "img/delete.jpg' width='20' height='20' align='center'></td></tr>";
var template = $(templatestring);
$("#addoption").button().click(function() {
        var newrow = $(template).clone();
        $(newrow).children().each(function() {
            switch($(this).attr('class')) {
                case 'itemId':
                    $(this).html('');
                    break;
                case 'Option':
                    var option=$('<input type="text" value=""/>');
                    $(this).append($(option));
                    $(this).find('input:text').val('11');
                    $(option).focus();

                    break;
                case 'Correct':
                    $(this).html('<input type="radio" class="Answer" name="correct"/>');
                    break;
                case 'Action':
                    $('input:button', this).val('Add');
                    break;
            }
        });
        $('#datatable tbody').append(newrow);
    });
```

If it is any help I am using google chrome.

Comment: Try using $(option).on('ready', $(this).focus());

Comment: This is not the problem, but you don't have to create a jquery object everytime you use `option` : http://jsfiddle.net/6eH9h/1/

Comment: What's `this` referring to? Could you please give a bit of context?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I was doing that earlier resorted to this in an attempt to make it work. Didnt work either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `$(this)`? If not in a selector function then `this` will refer to window. If you want to append to body you can do like this

```
var option=$('<input type="text" value=""/>');
$('body').append($(option)); // You can also use div , selector instead of body
$(option).focus();
```

[TD Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzGZM)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var option = $('<input type="text" value=""/>');
    $(this).append($(option));
    $(option).focus();
});
```

After OP update, I can see why above solutions are not working for you. You need to call `focus` after appending `input` to `table`. Try this:

```
var templatestring = "<tr><td class='itemId' style='display:none'></td><td id='tdelement' class='Correct'></td><td id='tdelement' class='Option'></td></td><td id='tdelement' class='Action'><input type='button' value='View' onclick='view(this)'/></td><td id='tdelement' class='Remove'><img src='" + STATIC_URL + "img/delete.jpg' width='20' height='20' align='center'></td></tr>";
var template = $(templatestring);
var option;
$("#addoption").button().click(function() {
    var newrow = $(template).clone();
    $(newrow).children().each(function() {
        switch ($(this).attr('class')) {
            case 'itemId':
                $(this).html('');
                break;
            case 'Option':
                option = $('<input type="text" value=""/>');
                $(this).append($(option));
                $(this).find('input:text').val('11');
                $(option).focus();

                break;
            case 'Correct':
                $(this).html('<input type="radio" class="Answer" name="correct"/>');
                break;
            case 'Action':
                $('input:button', this).val('Add');
                break;
        }
    });
    $('#datatable tbody').append(newrow);
    $(option).focus();
});
```

Comment: This is a <td></td> element if it satisfies you curiosity.
I don't think it matters over here.

Comment: Working `<td></td>` demo link added in answer

Comment: Difference is `click function` for `td selector` Either you have not used `selector` or not added in your OP

Comment: I have edited my question. You can see the complete context now.

Comment: Store `option` value in `global variable` and call `$(option).focus()` after `appending` `#datatable tbody`, answer updated